# Capybara auto revisit the same URL/null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

my test is simple. but this is failing `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css ".cards"`

```rb
test "it renders region's species" do
    # ... insert test data to db in here

    visit "/regions/galaxy"
    within(".cards") do
      assert_selector(".card", count: 3)
    end
end
```

in log I can see a everything is good except there is a second visit to `"/regions/null"`.
this can of course render a blank page.
how can this 2nd visit happen with "galaxy" replaced from null?

this worked fine for a long time. suddenly its failing.
I test by increasing `default_max_wait_time`but still same.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara won't just visit random urls, which means if it is going to '/regions/null' it's because your application is telling it to go to there.  Check your `test.log` to see whether it's returning a redirect from the original url the test visits, and if it is then you'll need to look at your code to see why.

Comment: Its only failing on my dev machine. on circleci its all green. I'm guessing maybe a webdriver issue.

Comment: @OshanWisumperuma doubtful it’s a webdriver issue - really check your test.log

Answer (score 0):

found a react application issue from /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.WRvy4J/chrome_debug.log file. a required prop value was undefined. after setting a default value now its all green.